# LinqToSQL join what type to use as return on List

Tags: c#

I got the join below, what type/class would I return to keep all the properties? This is the NorthWind database, which I think most guys are familiar with.

```
         var q =
               from a in db.GetTable<Order_Detail>()
               join b in db.GetTable<Product>() on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
               select a;
```

Comment: You'd want to `select new { a, b }` to get everything.

Comment: and how would I do that? I'm quite a newbie when it comes to LinqToSql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices, you can select it as an `anonymous type`, like this

```
 var q =
               from a in db.GetTable<Order_Detail>()
               join b in db.GetTable<Product>() on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
               select new { a, b };
```

This will give you an object `q` with `a` and `b` on it, so for example you can do:

`q.a.SomeOrderInformation`

`q.b.SomeProductInformation`

Or you can select it into a class.

Create a new class with the fields you want:

```
public class MyNewClass {
   public string MyOrderProperty {get; set;}
   public string MyProductProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Then populate it with:

```
 var q =
               from a in db.GetTable<Order_Detail>()
               join b in db.GetTable<Product>() on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
               select new MyNewClass { MyProductProperty = b.ProductId, MyOrderProperty = a.OrderName };
```

Change the fields/class name to fit I just made them up as I don't have access to northwind.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create a new anonymous type to return both values:

```
var q =
    from a in db.GetTable<Order_Detail>()
    join b in db.GetTable<Product>() on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
    select new 
    { 
        Order = a, 
        Product = b 
    };
```

Note that if you have your foreign keys set up properly, you shouldn't need to do an explicit join at all. You should be able to say `Order_Detail.Products` to get the `Product`s within an Order_Detail.